# Joomla 4 system plugin does not get parsed

Tags: php, joomla-extensions, joomla4

I did create a Joomla 4 plugin. The plugin should allow me to publish the value of a specific cell of a specific row identified by a specific colum within a specific dbase table from within the meta description of an article or menu item.

```
This is the format: {dbv table_prices|item_id|123|price}
```

Where

- dbv = the plugin name
- table_prices = table name
- item_id = the column to use
- 123 = the id of the row whitin column 'item_id'
- price = the column in the row to get the value from
- 

So in the article the meta description could look like:

```
Best travel book this week for only € {dbv table_prices|item_id|123|price}
```

where the plugin should ensure that the meta description after rendering in the front-end should look like this:

```
Best travel book this week for only € 50
```

assuming the value in the cell is 50.00

The plugin installs, it is enabled but the plugin snippets stays visible in the front-end. What could possible be wrong in the code?

```
class plgSystemDbv extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onAfterDispatch()
{
    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $activeItem = $menu->getActive();

    if ($activeItem && ($activeItem->type === 'article' || $activeItem->type === 'url')) {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $document = $app->getDocument();
        $description = $document->getMetaData('description');
        $matches = array();

        // Find all occurrences of {dbv ...} tags in the meta description
        preg_match_all('/{dbv\s+([^}]+)}/', $description, $matches);

        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            // Parse the parameters from the {dbv} tag
            $params = explode('|', $match);
            $table = trim($params[0]);
            $column = trim($params[1]);
            $row = trim($params[2]);
            $cell = trim($params[3]);

            // Get the ID value based on the specified column and row
            $id = $this->getValueFromColumn($activeItem, $column);

            if ($id !== null) {
                // Retrieve the value from the specified table, column, row, and cell
                $value = $this->getQueryValue($db, $table, $column, $id, $cell);

                if (!empty($value)) {
                    // Replace the {dbv} tag with the retrieved value
                    $description = str_replace('{dbv ' . $match . '}', $value, $description);
                }
            }
        }

        // Update the meta description with the modified content
        $document->setMetaData('description', $description);
    }
}

private function getValueFromColumn($item, $column)
{
    $columns = explode('|', $column);
    $currentItem = $item;

    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        if (isset($currentItem->$column)) {
            $currentItem = $currentItem->$column;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return $currentItem;
}

private function getQueryValue($db, $table, $idColumn, $idValue, $valueColumn)
{
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select($db->quoteName($valueColumn))
        ->from($db->quoteName($table))
        ->where($db->quoteName($idColumn) . ' = ' . $db->quote($idValue));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    return $db->loadResult();
}
}
```

`

I tried to use the oncontentprepare event since I am using that in a similar content plugin but that doesn't help either. I had a similar plugin for Joomla 3 that worked fine, though different code and J3 is quite different.

Comment: Please always post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. `getValueFromColumn()` is a very misleading method name -- it actually attempts to access a value from a delimited string of property names (as a path to potentially deep object properties).  If `$params` is already exploded on pipes, then there is no chance of `$column` having pipes to explode on.

Answer (score 0):

Change your plugin type from System to Content

Comment: A developer did create a similar plugin for J3 for me before. The one that was handling the snippet within the article itself was a content plugin at that time. The one that handled the meta description successfully was a system plugin. So I made the choice to stick to that. 

Could there be a reason why a system plugin was successful for J3 for the same capability and that is should now be a content plugin for that capability?

Comment: What I found out is that Joomla by default does not allow content plugins to be used in meta description fields. The way to do it is to use a system plugin